# How evaluate values for already checked boxes when page loads?

Tags: javascript

I have page for cinema's seats model. User picks seats and has real-time price is showing up. The next step is to go to checkouts but if user changes his mind and want to change to different seats and clicks back on the browser, then returns to seats selection page. I managed to keep selected seats by using session id check. But can't keep prices saved.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $inputs = $('.seats-c');
var $output_seats = $('#span-seats');
var $output_price = $('#span-price');
var $output_taxes = $('#span-taxes');
var $output_tot_price = $('#span-tot-price');
var input_val;
var seats_list_json;
var seats_list;
var seats;
var price;
var taxes;
var last_entered;
$inputs.on('click', function () {
    last_entered = this;
});
$inputs.on('change', function () {
    seats_list_json = $('#seatsList').val();
    seats_list = JSON.parse(seats_list_json);
    seats = 0;
    price = 0;
    taxes = 13; //%
    $inputs.each(function () {
        input_val = this.value;
        if (this.checked) {
            seats += 1;
            $.each(seats_list, function (key, value) {
                if (input_val === key) {
                    price += value;
                }
            });
        }
        if (seats > 4) {
            $(last_entered).prop("checked", false);
            box(null, "Warning !", "Maximum amount is 4 seats per transaction", "alert-box");
        }
    });
    $output_seats.html(seats);
    $output_price.html(price);
    $output_taxes.html(taxes + "% taxes = $" + (price * (taxes / 100)).toFixed(2));
    $output_tot_price.html((price * ((taxes / 100) + 1)).toFixed(2));
}); });
```

Comment: What type of data **seats_list_json** is holding?

Comment: It holds Object (key, value)

Comment: It will be good if you can provide some sample data that this variable hold, it will help others to run your piece of code on their machine.

Comment: It comes from Java Servlet via jsp page

Comment: Put **console.log(seats_list_json)** before parsing, it will print the data in console, then you can copy it from there.

Comment: Here it is  (only little part) - contains: key - seat number, value - price{"E1":13.25,"E2":13.25,"E3":13.25,"E4":13.25,"A1":11.25,"E5":18,"A2":11.25,"E6":18

Comment: What is issue you are facing now? price value not updating on seat selection?

Comment: It is updating, but the issue is, once user goes to next page, which is check out, and returns back, price is not showing, even thought seats are showing selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is still un-clear. but based on my understanding below changes you can implement.

Separate your calculate price to function. Like below `calculatePrice`.

Now on `pageLoad` and on `change` of checkbox call same function.

On `pageLoad` also call same function to get updated price on `document.ready`.

Here below sample code can helps you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $inputs = $('.seats-c');
  var $output_seats = $('#span-seats');
  var $output_price = $('#span-price');
  var $output_taxes = $('#span-taxes');
  var $output_tot_price = $('#span-tot-price');
  var input_val;
  var seats_list_json;
  var seats_list;
  var seats;
  var price;
  var taxes;
  var last_entered;

  seats_list = [{
      ch_1: 100
    },
    {
      ch_2: 20
    },
    {
      ch_3: 20
    },
    {
      ch_4: 20
    },
    {
      ch_5: 20
    }
  ];

  function calculatePrice() {

    seats = 0;
    price = 0;
    taxes = 13; //%
    $inputs.each(function() {
      input_val = this.id;
      if (this.checked) {
        seats += 1;;
        $.each(seats_list, function(key, value) {

          if (value.hasOwnProperty(input_val)) {
            price += value[input_val];
          }
        });
      }
    });
    $output_seats.html(seats);
    $output_price.html(price);
    $output_taxes.html(taxes + "% taxes = $" + (price * (taxes / 100)).toFixed(2));
    $output_tot_price.html((price * ((taxes / 100) + 1)).toFixed(2));
  }


  calculatePrice();

  $inputs.on('click', function() {
    last_entered = this;
  });
  $inputs.on('change', function() {
    calculatePrice();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="ch_1" class="seats-c" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" id="ch_2" class="seats-c" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" id="ch_3" class="seats-c" />
<input type="checkbox" id="ch_4" class="seats-c" />
<input type="checkbox" id="ch_5" class="seats-c" />
<br/> -seats- <span id="span-seats"></span>
<br/> -price- <span id="span-price"></span>
<br/> -taxes- <span id="span-taxes"></span>
<br/> -total- <span id="span-tot-price"></span>
<br/>
```

Comment: Great thx Yogen, u solved it. It works now, u got it right, I needed to make separate function and to call it from ready and change queries

Comment: @Roms Glad it helps you